# Update custom plugin with WP-CLI

Tags: plugin-development, updates, wp-cli

I made a custom plugin for inserting staging / production versions of a Google Tag Manager container based on the server's IP address.

How do I make it compatible with WP-CLI so it will update when I run the `wp plugin update --all` command?

Comment: you would do this the same way you'd make it update with the standard updater as they both use the same mechanism, WP 5.8 introduced the needed APIs and filters so the answer will be in the release notes and make blogs. What that is though I don't quite remember though so I can't write an answer below, but maybe that'll help someone to write up something :)

Comment: @TomJNowell I have only ever made personal use plugins and never had issues with manual updates. Since using WP-CLI I'm trying to move towards more automated but haven't solved this piece yet.

Comment: Did you submit to the Worpress Repository already?

Comment: @rudtek no it's just for personal use to help simplify our internal management of servers. I am operating on the assumption it's possible to have WP-CLI update a plugin that's not in the WordPress Plugin directory ... but I haven't found the how yet

Comment: see https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/introducing-update-uri-plugin-header-in-wordpress-5-8/

Comment: I'm not really sure that it is.  Even if it were, it would be easier for a personal project just to do it through Git.  Can you push it that way?

Comment: if it's for internal use, you may be better with a tool such as composer or git version control to manage this

Comment: @TomJNowell that's a possibility, but honestly I am concurrently moving towards a Git / GitHub workflow. As a one person team, I've been old-schooling this with a dev / prod pair of servers per WP instance, and using hostfile rewrites to the dev IP for all development work. So my conceptual understanding of Git has not really had practical application. Based on my understanding, you're suggesting a Git repo for the plugin locally, configured to Push to multiple remotes, each instance it's installed on? Ideally, I'd like `wp plugin update --all` to handle this, but I'll look at both.

Answer (score 3):

You would implement this:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/introducing-update-uri-plugin-header-in-wordpress-5-8/

First you would add a `Update URI:`  header to your plugin with a custom domain.

Second, you would add a filter to your plugin, using the filter name `update_plugins_{$hostname}` where `{$hostname}` is the value you gave your `Update URI:` . E.g. `Update URI: example.com` would have the filter `update_plugins_example.com`.

In this filter, you would then run some code that checks if there is an update for your plugin. When your code is finished running, it will return the answer.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_plugins_hostname/

The value you return will need to be an array containing the values in the parameter section. Or it can return `false` to indicate there are not updates.

The second and third parameters can be used to figure out which plugin WP is asking for update information.

There are very few examples of this filter being used, it's very new and the documentation describes how to use it instead of demonstrating.

Here's some untested pseudocode of what I think such a filter might look like:

```php
add_filter( 'update_plugins_example.com', function( $update, array $plugin_data, string $plugin_file, $locales ) {
    // only check this plugin
    if ( $plugin_file !== 'myplugin.php' ) {
        return $update;
    }

    // already done update check elsewhere
    if ( ! empty( $update ) ) {
        return $update;
    }

    // CODE GOES HERE TO FIND UPDATE, maybe ask a server what
    // the latest version number is and call `version_compare`?
    $is_update_available = true;

    // no updates found
    if ( ! $is_update_available ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Update found?
    return [
        'slug' => 'myplugin',
        'version' => '9000',
        'url' => 'example.com/myplugin/',
        'package' => 'example.com/newversion.zip',
    ];
}, 10, 4 );
```

As for the actual checking of the update, that depends entirely on you, there is no canonical correct way to do that.

For example, you could toss a coin and return gibberish values. You could make a HTTP request to a file on a server to fetch the latest version number and compare it to the version installed. You could implement a license key check, or ping Githubs API for release versions, etc. It is entirely up to you.

Comment: Nice work, Tom!

Comment: Very much appreciated. Digging into this now. This already clarifies so much about it. Thank you kindly.

Comment: if you need to make any minor adjustments let me know, it was frustrating being unable to find any examples of this and having to build my own so I'd like this one to be as good as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Support for plugins that do not reside on wordpress.org appears to be supported by `wp plugin install` and MAY also be supported by `wp plugin update`.  Daniel addresses a syntax issue with that feature here: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2170

Documentation for `install` indicates acceptance of a plugin slug (.org) or the path/URL to the ZIP file:
https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/install/

Have you tried `wp plugin update "your_plugin_url"`?

Daniel also references the ability of non-WP.org plugins to introduce an update in his answer to a tangentially related question on Github:

```
For a non-WordPress.org plugin to introduce an update, it needs to filter the update_plugins transient to return what's called a "download offer" for the plugin.

WP Remote has a relevant piece of support documentation: https://wpremote.com/support-center/integrating-wp-remote/adding-wp-remote-support-premium-theme-plugin/
```

Here's a direct link:
https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1662

Hope that helps.

Comment: those WP CLI issues predate the update mechanism introduced in WP 5.8 that changed this, see https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/introducing-update-uri-plugin-header-in-wordpress-5-8/

Comment: @jdm2112 I have tried `wp plugin update [url]` using both a path to a directory containing the plugin, and using a path to a zip containing a plugin. I have also added the Update URI: header, trying both a path and a .zip. The contents of the directory and the zip have a higher version number in the header as well. I feel like it's missing something small that I am personally unaware of, which indicates to WP-CLI that there is an update available ...

Comment: @TomJNowell and @jdm2112 I also tried using the `--url=` flag with and without quotes around the url to the dir and the zip to no avail.

Comment: Reading the notes on 5.8 update that Tom shared, updating non .org plugins appears to be intentionally blocked now.

`If the value of this new field matches any URI other than https://wordpress.org/plugins/{$slug}/ or w.org/plugin/{$slug}, WordPress will not attempt to update it.`

Comment: @jdm2112 I saw that as well, but wasn't sure if that "WordPress will not attempt" part applied to WP-CLI as well ... I sorta figured, but didn't want that to be the case ;)

Comment: It seems like the current best solution is to `wp plugin delete [slug]` then `wp plugin install [url]` which isn't entirely ideal, but it appears its where we are at.

Comment: That's not true, If the value of that plugin header is not wp.org, then WP itself won't try to check for updates, but the filters mentioned in the post can fill in the necessary data to enable it. This is because you would need to do a HTTP request to your server to ask it about updates and that's different for different plugins and vendors, e.g. do you do a license check? etc

Comment: @TomJNowell can you elaborate on the HTTP request? Perhaps naively I was expecting that the Version header in conjunction with the Update URI header was all that was needed to "compare" when running `wp plugin list` or `wp plugin update --all` ... I'm not a complete WP noob, but this is my first attempt at a plugin which I don't intend to manage completely manually.

Comment: @whakawaehere you would need to build that part yourself, WP provides a filter that gives you an opportunity to figure out in code if there are updates or not and return the answer. How you get that answer though is entirely up to you, it could be literally anything that you want. This means you will need to implement the server side from scratch, aka your plugin needs to contact something to ask it what the latest version is, and that can be anything you want, it's up to you to do that. When you've done it, return it in that filter and WP will act as if it did it itself