# Run a function only once when logging into dashboard

Tags: plugins, functions

I want the Pro version of my plugin to do a version check once when an Administrator logs into the dashboard.

At the moment I am connecting to my API using `wp_remote_get()` in the main plugin file, but it is being triggered every time the dashboard reloads, for each site that has the plugin installed.  That's a lot of unnecessary connections :P

There must be a way to "only run this function once per administrator login session", but I can't find anything about it.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: a user can login to a site without touching the admin area, is it specifically when a user logs in, or when a user first opens the dashboard that you're interested in? And most importantly, _why_ do you need to do this? Context is hugely important here!!

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell - it is specifically when an administrator logs in.  Though if that is tricky, when anyone logs in is fine.  It is the "once" that is important, I can code around that.  The version check is done to notify of a plugin upgrade since this Pro version isn't available through the WP repository.

Comment: I see, would that not be better done using the official 3rd aprty plugin update API, a cron job, or by recording when you last checked for updates and then waiting until the difference was more than a certain time? Or on the plugin check update hook? I'm not sure why this has anything to do with logging in or the role of the user

Comment: I will likely end up just checking once per day as suggested, I thought there might be a hook or filter or something that handled it.

If you want to add your comment as an answer I will accept it, might help someone else down the track.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: there is an official mechanism for this, I wrote an answer a while back here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/401530/736 if you implement that then WP itself will check for updates and call your custom code for your specific plugin. Then you don't need to do any scheduling or hooking into logins etc, and you'll get WP CLI updates and a GUI for free